# Multiselect dropdown is not working in my mvc project

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

Even tough the multiselect dropdown is created ... it is not displaying in the ui/screen .... im using this plugin http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

```
var mymultiselect = $(document.createElement("select")).attr("multiple","multiple").addClass("multiselect").multiselect();

mymultiselect.append('<option>"blah"</option');
mymultiselect.append('<option>"bloh"</option');
```

Comment: can u post ur html and jquery.. it would help us to understand ur problom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code

```
var mymultiselect = $(document.createElement("select")).attr("multiple","multiple").addClass("multiselect");
mymultiselect.append('<option>"blah"</option');
mymultiselect.append('<option>"bloh"</option');
$('body').append(mymultiselect); // create ur select element
$(".multiselect").multiselect(); // then initialize ur plugin
```

Note: `dont forget to link multiselect plugin to your code`